# Android app not searchable by Title - only by package name

Tags: android, search, google-play

I've just published my first Android app. While it is on the Play Store, I am unable to find it using the Title that I specified for it in the Developer Console ("Meal Timer"). In fact if I search for "Meal Timer" on Google Play none of the first page of results are actually called "Meal Timer".

On the other hand if I search for "Mealtimer" (without the space) I can find my app. "Mealtimer" is the name of the app in my Java package.

Why I am I unable to find my app by searching using its title?

Answer (score 0):

Finding your application within the Play Store is completely down to the name of your app and how saturated the keywords your'e using are.

Lets say for instance your app is called "Wallpapers HD". There are hundreds of apps that have the keyword variation of "Wallpapers HD" in the name so when you release your app, the chances of that app being listed with very few downloads and ratings within the first page is extremly unlikely because there will be hundreds of other apps that have the same keywords and many more downloads and ratings giving that app more keyword strength.

Now lets say your app is called "Table Spoon Milkshake". Your app will be very more likely to be listed within the first page because not many apps would have those keywords in the title.

So you will need to wait until your app has more downloads and ratings so the keyword strength of your app will increase giving it more visiblity when you search for it.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not the position of my app in the ranking that's the problem - it's the fact that it doesn't show up AT ALL if I search using its title. There are 250 results for "Meal Timer", and mine is not ANYWHERE on the list (even though it's one of a very small number with that exact name)

Comment: How long has your application been on the market for?

Comment: Only a couple of days

Comment: Give it a few more days and it will be more visable, mine always take at most 3 - 6 days to be visible depending on what kind of app.

Comment: It's now been 5 days since I published my app and I can still only locate it using the package name, not the app name - i.e. if I search for "mealtimer" I can find it, but if I search for "Meal Timer" it does not appear anywhere in the search results. I'm guessing that I have not specified the app name correctly in my AndroidManifest - which element should I be using for this?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the name you specify in the Android Manifest, I just use android:label="@string/app_name" under application. Also, a tip for making your game/app more visible when searching, make sure in the description you use key words. Like for instance your app is a meal timer, so if you plaster meal timer a few times in a sentence that makes sense your app will become more visible, descriptions act sort of like keywords. Other then waiting for your app to get more downloads and ratings to increase visibility, it's up to Google to dictate your apps keyword ranking.

Comment: The issue isn't ranking - the app is completely invisible if you search the Play Store using its name. The search returns about 250 results, but my app isn't anywhere in the results, despite having a name which matches the search term exactly. The app description also has the phrase "meal timer" at least 3 times in its content. ????

Comment: Well, Other than what I have told you and from my previous experience, all you can do is wait for it to become visible. I too, had the same issue as you with my app being invisible, I just marketed my app, waited and it finally became visible. Good luck!

Comment: Well, when I said invisible I meant that it doesn't show up if you search for it by name - only if you enter the package name (which realistically nobody is going to do). This either sounds like a bug in Google Play's indexing system or a misunderstanding on my part re. how app naming works. As it's now been listed for a whole a week I don't expect the situation to change much TBH.

Comment: Your app is so bad in search ranking to show in first 250 results.