# Can only see app in google play if searched with no spaces in title

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Okay so this question has already been asked here but was not fully answered:
[Android app not searchable by Title - only by package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827541/android-app-not-searchable-by-title-only-by-package-name)

This guy had the exact same problem as me. My app has been up for about 3 days and I can't see it even if search by the exact name and the developer name too. However, when I don't put a space in the title, it shows up. Now I know that common words in title will result in a less likely chance of app being shown in search results, but the problem is the app doesn't show up AT ALL, even if I scroll all the way down. My problem isn't with where my app is in the list, but that it isn't shown even if I scroll to the bottom of the 250 results. Could my manifest be causing this?

Comment: No, your app doesn't get in the top 250.

Comment: So where does it go? And there isn't a button for Show More anymore that button ends after 250... so I don't understand how you are supposed to view apps not in the 250 range..

Answer (score 0):

Google Play store doesn't use just the title to arrive at the results. There's an article here that explains somewhat what they use when searching: http://www.insidemobileapps.com/2013/05/17/google-discloses-how-search-for-google-play-works-for-the-first-time-12-percent-of-dau-search-for-apps-daily/.

Unfortunately, if you app uses common words (like meal and timer) and has just been published so there are no reviews and +1's, it's bad news for you - it'll get buried in the results.

Comment: I should still be able to see it at like the bottom.. Why does it not show up at all?

Comment: And also, how does any app then get any reviews in the first place? Kind of a paradox..

Comment: You could send your app to people who you know might be interested in it, blogs and online magazines that review mobile apps, blogs interested in dieting etc. Of course, you shouldn't spam them, but explain what it does and how it's different from the other apps etc. In short, marketing and PR. It was easier when there weren't million apps on the market.

Comment: And it doesn't show at the bottom because probably there are more than 250 apps that google finds in the search, and yours doesn't rank above 250 so it gets left out.

Comment: If I changed the app name to be a bit more unique, would that help? And if I were to do this, would I also have to change everything in the manifest or would changing the title in the developer console page be enough?

Comment: Making it more unique would help, sure, but they will people be able to find it? You can just change it in the developer console, the app name in the manifest is what's visible on the phone - but it is advisable they're equal.